# Как вывести данные из несколько связанных таблиц Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Есть три таблицы Тесты, Вопросы и Ответы. Мне нужно что бы когда человек выбирал тестБ отображались вопросы с вариантами ответа. Сейчас я получаю только сами вопросы.

```
    class LearnTest extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = false;

    public function question()
    {

        return $this->hasMany(LearnQuestion::class);
    }
}
```

Миграция тест:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('learn_tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id');
        $table->foreign('course_id',     'learn_question_course_fk')->on('learn_courses')->references('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Вопросы

```
class LearnQuestion extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = false;

    public function test()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo(LearnTest::class);
    }

    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LearnAnswer::class);

    }
}
```

Миграция вопрос

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('learn_questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('type_question');
        $table->integer('point');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('test_id');
        $table->foreign('test_id', 'learn_question_test_fk')->on('learn_tests')->references('id');
        $table->timestamps();


    });
}
```

Ответы

```
class LearnAnswer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = false;

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(LearnQuestion::class);

    }
}
```

Миграция ответ:

```
    */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('learn_answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('answer');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('correct')->nullable();
         $table->foreign('question_id', 'learn_answer_learn_question_fk')->on('learn_questions')->references('id');
        $table->timestamps();
```

В контроллере

```
    public function question(Request $request)
{

    $test = $request->test_id;

    $questions = LearnQuestion::where('test_id', '=', $test)->get();

    return view('learn.test.question', compact('questions'));
}
```

Проблему решила неправильно был написан запрос в контроллере

```
$questions = LearnQuestion::join('learn_answers', 'learn_questions.id', '=','learn_answers.question_id' )->
        where('test_id', '=', $test)->get();
```

Но теперь проблема в том что он выводит на форме, Вопрос 1 - Ответ 1, Вопрос 2 - Ответ 2 Как можно сделать так что бы он не дублировал запись вопроса

Comment: Миграции свои ещё приведите. Потому что так может быть не понятно, в чём конкретно проблема

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос, как я понимаю, в области получения данных на основании связей между моделями.

Контроллер у вас правильный, чуть можно модифицировать.

```
public function question(Request $request)
{
    $test = Test::findOrFail($request->test_id);

    $questions = $test->questions->load('answers'); // load - жадная загрузка

    return view('learn.test.question', compact('test', 'questions'));
}
```

Выводите варианты ответов в представлении:

`/resources/views/tests/show.blade.php`

```
{{ $test->name }}

@foreach($questions as $question)
    {{ $question->name }}

    @foreach($$question->answers as $answer)
         {{ $answer->name }}
    @endforeach
    
@endforeach
```

Comment: Если попробовать так то выдает ошибку

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: learn_questions.learn_test_id (SQL: select * from "learn_questions" where "learn_questions"."learn_test_id" = 1 and "learn_questions"."learn_test_id" is not null)

Comment: вам нужно явно указать связь по полям в отношениях, например в классе LearnQuestion для метода   test() возвращаемое значение будет что-то типа  return $this->belongsTo(LearnTest::class, 'id', 'learn_test_id'); 
Почитайте чуть больше про используемые методы BelongsTo и HasMany в документации